# Trigger AFTER UPDATE - Trouble w/ conditional IF

Tags: sql-server, triggers

An SQL rookie here, looking for some assistance.
I am completing a sample project and am trying to work out the following use case but am stuck.

A customer cancels their membership and does not return a rented DVD, necessitating that a $25 DVD replacement fee be charged to their account.

Tables involved:  Customer, Rented_out, Bill

Essentially, I am trying to create a trigger than will execute if the following conditions are true in order to insert an entry into the bill table:
1. Customer_status in the customer table is updated to 'Inactive'
2. In Rented_out table, that updated customer has a NULL value for the date_returned block (meaning an unreturned DVD).

Below is what I wrote but right now the trigger executes any time a customer's status is changed (to any value), not specifically to 'Inactive' and regardless of whether or not they have a NULL value in the date_returned block of the rented_out table.  I am unable to figure out how to apply those restrictions.  Also, it is possible for the customer to have multiple rented out items so the $25 fee being entered into the bill table would need to be multiplied by the number of NULL values in the rented_out table for that customer.

I realize you might need the rest of the code so if that's the case, please don't hesitate to ask.

```
CREATE TRIGGER charge_for_unreturned_movie ON customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN customer
    DECLARE @customer_id INT;
    DECLARE @customer_status VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @bill_number INT;
    DECLARE @bill_amount_due DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE @bill_payment_due_date DATE;
    SET @bill_number = ((SELECT MAX(bill_number) +1 FROM bill));
    SET @customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM inserted);
    SET @bill_amount_due = 25.00;
    SET @bill_payment_due_date = GETDATE()+30;
        IF UPDATE (customer_status)
            INSERT INTO bill(bill_number, customer_id, bill_amount_due, bill_payment_due_date)
            VALUES  (@bill_number, @customer_id, @bill_amount_due, @bill_payment_due_date)
            PRINT 'New charge added to customer account when status is changed to "Inactive"!';
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers can do cool stuff, but there are some things you need to be aware of. First and most important: triggers operate on sets of data so doing something like `SET @customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM inserted);` is almost certainly doomed to fail as the `inserted` table can hold more than one row (unless you only ever update a single customer at once). Knowing this it's easy to rewrite the trigger to become set aware.

A note: maybe the bill number shouldn't be retrieved and calculated but rather be an auto incrementing identity column in the bill table?

I included some comments in the code, but it should be easy enough to follow.

```
CREATE TRIGGER charge_for_unreturned_movie ON customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- retrieve the max bill number, or 0 if there are no bills
    DECLARE @bill_number INT;
    SET @bill_number = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(bill_number),0) FROM bill);

    DECLARE @bill_amount_due DECIMAL(10,2);
    SET @bill_amount_due = 25.00;

    DECLARE @bill_payment_due_date DATE;
    SET @bill_payment_due_date = GETDATE() + 30;

    -- if there has been an update
    IF UPDATE (customer_status)
    BEGIN    
       -- set up a table to hold the records that needs to be billed
       DECLARE @to_be_billed TABLE (
          bill_number int identity(1,1), 
          customer_id int, 
          unreturned int
       )

       -- fill the table with records where status has changed to 'Inactive'
       -- but disregard those who already were 'Inactive' (through the join 
       -- against the deleted table. Insert only those customers that have 
       -- unreturned items.
       -- Insert the customer_id and number of unreturned items.
       INSERT @to_be_billed (customer_id, unreturned) 
       SELECT i.customer_id, COUNT(*) 
       FROM inserted i 
       JOIN rented_out r ON i.customer_id = r.customer_id
       JOIN deleted d ON i.customer_id = d.customer_id 
       WHERE i.customer_status = 'Inactive' 
         AND r.date_returned IS NULL 
         AND d.customer_status <> 'Inactive'
       GROUP BY i.customer_id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
    END
    -- if the last insert had a @@rowcount over zero insert records into the bill table
    -- increment the bill_number using the identity column
    -- calculate the charge as count of unreturned items * @bill_amount_due
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
     BEGIN
      INSERT INTO bill (bill_number, customer_id, bill_amount_due, bill_payment_due_date)
      SELECT @bill_number + bill_number, customer_id, unreturned * @bill_amount_due, @bill_payment_due_date 
      FROM @to_be_billed
      PRINT 'New charge added to customer account when status is changed to "Inactive"!';
     END
END;
```